# How does the if statement in PHP work?

Tags: php, mysql

The code below does exactly what it's expected to do. It adds a client into the database successfully. But I never told the query to execute or add a new client all I did was store the query in a variable and checked to see if it was valid in the if statement. I need some help understanding how the query executed.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clients(id, name, email, phone, address, company, notes, date_added) VALUES(NULL, '$clientName', '$clientEmail', '$clientPhone', '$clientAddress', '$clientCompany', '$clientNotes', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            // if query was successful
            if( $result ){

                header("LOCATION: clients.php?update=success");

            } else{

                // something went wrong
                echo "Error: $query <br>" . mysqli_error($connection);

            }
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` runs the query against the db

Comment: You did, in fact, fun the query. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: $result variable is storing the returned value from the mysqli_query function being called. When you evaluate $result in the if statement you are checking if it has returned true or false.

Comment: So does the variable containing the query execute itself?

Comment: ^^^ um what? the function `mysqli_query` runs the query, that's what the function is for. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php "mysqli::query -- mysqli_query — Performs a query on the database"

Comment: `mysqli_query` executes your query. Do you understand what people tell you?

Comment: @Araymer Please, try **not** to link to w3schools and instead reference the official documentation. w3schools is notoriously out of date and tends to promote dangerously coding bad habits.

Comment: Whoops, copied the wrong google search result address. Apologies.

Comment: @Araymer It's not a big deal, but links like that can lead people wildly astray and then Stack Overflow has to repair the damage that's done.

Answer (score 2):

The way you should be doing this is a little more self-explanatory:

```
// Prepare this query with placeholders for where the user data will go.
// This creates a prepared statement handle ($stmt)
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO clients(name, email, phone, address, company, notes, date_added)
  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

// Bind the user data to the statement so it will be escaped properly
// and inserted correctly.
$stmt->bind_param(
  "ssssss",
  $clientName,
  $clientEmail,
  $clientPhone,
  $clientAddress,
  $clientCompany,
  $clientNotes
);

// Execute the statement now that everthing is in place. This actually
// sends the query to the MySQL server to be executed and waits
// for the result. The result of this function call indicates success
// or failure.
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  // Query was successful then `execute()` returns a logically true value
  // and this block of code will run.
  header("Location: clients.php?update=success");
} else {
  // If that previous condition didn't trigger, then we end up here and
  // this code will run instead.
  echo "Error: $query <br>" . $connection->error;
}
```

If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column don't specify it in your list of `VALUES`, you can omit it and it will be populated automatically. Any column with a `NULL` default can also be omitted. There's no point in force-inserting `NULL` if that's how it will end up anyway.

You also need to pay careful attention to how you insert your data. You cannot use string interpolation to do this, it's [extremely dangerous](http://bobby-tables.com/). The [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method takes care of adding the data in a safe manner if you've created a prepared statement that has placeholder values (`?`). This all but guarantees your code will be safe, secure and free from escaping errors that can take a lot of time to identify and repair.

I've also switched this to use the object-oriented style of `mysqli`. Not only is this significantly less verbose, it also becomes more clear as to what the operation is being performed on. `$stmt->function()` is obviously something making use of or manipulating the `$stmt` object. If it's just one argument of many that can be harder to identify.

Specifying arguments directly to functions instead of leaning on these intermediate variables is also a good habit to get into. Things like `$sql` tend to clutter up your code and confuse the intent of that string, plus if you have several of them you're juggling, like `$sql3` and `$sql8` there's an opportunity to make a tiny typo that causes real problems.